# Docusign Go live " Review" not working

Tags: sandbox, docusignapi

I have a sandbox account where I made 20+ error-free transactions using Java SDK but the review is failing. I can not submit without selecting the date. support guys are telling to post the question on stack overflow. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

For go-live issues, please contact DocuSign via the go-live@docusign.com email address. Note that the team's business hours are for Seattle, Washington state, USA.